# Determine if a chain of keys is existant in hashes

Tags: ruby

I'm writing some ruby code that goes to the value of a hash of a hash of a hash....

```
amz_price_info.raw["Offers"]["Offer"]["OfferListing"]["Price"]["FormattedPrice"]
```

I want to access this code only when the structor of the code is available. Currently, my code is this:

```
    #amz_price_info.raw.class == Hashie::Mash
    price = if amz_price_info.raw["Offers"]
        if amz_price_info.raw["Offers"]["Offer"]
            if amz_price_info.raw["Offers"]["Offer"]["OfferListing"]
                if amz_price_info.raw["Offers"]["Offer"]["OfferListing"]["Price"]
                    if amz_price_info.raw["Offers"]["Offer"]["OfferListing"]["Price"]["FormattedPrice"]
                        amz_price_info.raw["Offers"]["Offer"]["OfferListing"]["Price"]["FormattedPrice"]
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

How do I refactor my code to be less verbose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one way if you do not want to define extra methods or introduce some libraries.

```
amz_price_info.raw
.fetch("Offers", {})
.fetch("Offer", {})
.fetch("OfferListing", {})
.fetch("Price", {})
.fetch("FormattedPrice", nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

This method will allow you to search down a hash for any number of keys, returning `nil` if the path does not exist:

```
def find_value(hash, keys)
  keys.inject(hash.dup) do |prev, key| 
    prev && prev[key] ? prev[key] : nil
  end
end
```

Example:

```
info = { "Offers" => { "Offer" => { 
         "OfferListing" => { "Price" => 
       { "FormattedPrice" => 10 }}}}}

keys = %w[Offers Offer OfferListing Price FormattedPrice]
puts find_value(info, keys)                # => 10
puts find_value({"Offers" => {}}, keys)    # => nil
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by louism I would do it this way:

```
keys = %w[Offers Offer OfferListing Price FormattedPrice]
price = amz_price_info.raw
keys.each{|k| price = (price||{})[k]}
```

edit: as noted by Niklas in comment

```
# This will return price or nil
keys.inject(amz_price_info.raw) { |price, k| (price || {})[k] }
```

Comment: This can also be written as `keys.inject(amz_price_info.raw) { |price, k| (price || {})[k] }`

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 2.3+, use `Hash.dig`:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig

Your code can simply be:

```
amz_price_info.dig("Offers", "Offer", "OfferListing", "Price", "FormattedPrice")
```